# Cocoa : getting previous view's title

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm building a navigation based app (few views embedded in a navigation controller).
I'm wondering if I can get the title property from inside view B of the previous view (view A) and NSLog it out for example!

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Look at UINavigationController's [`viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) property.

That returns an array of the view controllers behind the one the user is currently looking at.  So look at the last view controller (or "n-2, where n is the nmber of items in the array", [according to the Apple documentation I linked for you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers)), and you can get your title from that view controller's nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

ControllerA myController;
For(int i = 0, i <[activeControllerArray  count], i++) {
    if([[activeViewController objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[ControllerA class]) {
        myController = [activeViewController objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",myController.title);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewControllerA *viewA = (ViewControllerA *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2];

NSLog(@"%@",viewA.title);

Answer (score 0):

Class A
.m file

```
{
   NSString *titleA = @"Khalid"; 
   ClassB *bObj = [[ClassB alloc] init];
   bObj.title = titleA;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:bObj animated:YES];
}
```